# AWS Beanstalk Spot Instance Types and Ordering

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When configuring instance types for Beanstalk spot instances there's a note:

"Add acceptable instance types for your fleet. Change their order to set the launch priority of On-Demand Instances. This order doesn't affect Spot Instances. We recommend a minimum of two instance types. Learn more"

Which makes me wonder, if order is not used to determine which spot instance is used, then what is?

Answer (score 0):

If you have spot instances it can be configured to choose the instance type via one of the two schemes:

- `capacity-optimized` - Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling allocates your instances from the Spot Instance pool with optimal capacity for the number of instances that are launching. Deploying in this way helps you make the most efficient use of spare EC2 capacity.
- `lowest-price` - Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling allocates your instances from the number (N) of Spot Instance pools that you specify and from the pools with the lowest price per unit at the time of fulfillment.

More information regarding spot instances ordering is available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/asg-purchase-options.html#asg-spot-strategy).

Comment: is it possible to do this from elastic beanstalk directly ? or do you have to go directly to the asg that the beanstalk creates to do this?